# Dealing with dialog box in Watir

Tags: watir

I have issue dealing with following scenario.

I am writing test script which will log me in to the system using google chrome.

I am reading data from excel.

First set of data has incorrect username/password combination.

Scenario is when incorrect password is entered, pop-up window appears with message that Username/Password not correct.

In this case, I should be able to close the pop-up window and watir should read next set of data from excel until correct username/password combination is met.

---

Issue is I am not sure how to detect pop-up dialog box. It has following code:

```
<div id="alertMsg" style="width: auto; min-height: 76.69999980926514px; height: auto;" class="ui-dialog-content ui-widget-content"><div class="dialogBoxTitle">&nbsp;</div>
<div class="alertMessage pointSearch">    
    <form name="saveComfortModelForm" class="pointSearchFrm">
        <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%" height="100%" class="pointSearchTable">
            <tbody><tr>
                <td>Login failed due to invalid password or username</td>
            </tr>
        </tbody></table>    
    </form>
</div></div>
```

Also there is link clicking which will close the pop-up. Code is as follows:

```
<div class="ui-dialog-titlebar ui-widget-header ui-corner-all ui-helper-clearfix">
<span class="ui-dialog-title" id="ui-dialog-title-alertMsg">&nbsp;</span>
<a href="#" class="ui-dialog-titlebar-close ui-corner-all" role="button">
<span class="ui-icon ui-icon-closethick">close</span>
</a>
</div>
```

I should be able to close the window when this message is displayed.

Answer (score 0):

You can detect if the popup dialog box is displayed by checking one of its element's visibility. This can be done with the `visible?` or `present?` methods. Try:

```
browser.div(:id => "alertMsg").present?
#=> Returns true if popup is displayed, false if not displayed
```

You can close the popup by clicking the close link:

```
browser.link(:class => "ui-dialog-titlebar-close").click
```

The watir part of the logic could be something like:

```
begin
  #Execute your logic to sign in with the next user/password

  #Check if the sign in was successful
  sign_in_successful = not(browser.div(:id => "alertMsg").present?)
  unless sign_in_successful
    browser.link(:class => "ui-dialog-titlebar-close").click
  end
end until sign_in_successful
```

Update: It seems that some [do not prefer the begin-while/until](http://rosettacode.org/wiki/Loops/Do-while#Ruby) and a loop should be used instead:

```
loop do
  #Execute your logic to sign in with the next user/password

  if browser.div(:id => "alertMsg").present?
    browser.link(:class => "ui-dialog-titlebar-close").click
  else
    break
  end
end
```

end